# Cheat Mode Not working NEI

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, minecraft-technic-pack

I have the *Not Enough Items* mod in attack of the b-team (I'm using technic launcher). I set it to cheat mode but when I drag the item to my inventory it doesn't drop into my inventory it just disappears.

Anyone know why?

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Answer (score 1):

I found that in order for you to be able to give yourself something with cheat mode in NEI, you need to set the gamemode to **creative** when you create the world.